# Spring security: log in using roles from database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I have 3 tables in db: `USER(login,password)`, `ROLE(role_name)` and `USER_ROLE_LINK (user_id, role_id)`

I want to give access to specific pages for users with specific roles.

I have this class where I configured security:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select login, password, active from USER where login=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select ur.user_id, ur.role_id from USER u inner join USER_ROLE_LINK ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.login=?");
    }
}
```

It works fine, and only those users who have at least one role can access the app. Now I want to give access to specific pages for users with specific roles, how to do it?

I've tried this: `antMatchers("/mypage").hasRole("MODERATOR")` but it throws `403 error`. How should I tell `Spring` to look for an user's roles from `ROLE` table's `role_name` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine?

No, you have wrong query string in `.authoritiesByUsernameQuery` method argument.

The query return type i.e, resultset should be username and role as

```
SELECT username, role
```

If join query results in resultset column name as given below:

[image]

You should modify into as given below:

[image]

By using alias `SELECT ud.username AS username, rm.name AS role`

> I've tried this: antMatchers("/mypage").hasRole("MODERATOR") but it throws 403 error

It will not work because your authorization part was incorrect.

> How should I tell Spring to look for an user's roles from ROLE table's role_name column?

It needs complete configuration of authentication and authorization. Refer below for the same.

I will give one working example:

Consider your requirement has similar three tables `userdetails`, `rolemaster`, and `user_role_mapping` as given below.

[image]

Then your configuration will be

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
    //If you want to store plain password you can use NoOpPasswordEncoder
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from userdetails where userName=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "SELECT ud.username AS username, rm.name AS role FROM user_role_mapping map " + 
                        "INNER JOIN userdetails ud ON map.userId = ud.id " + 
                        "INNER JOIN rolemaster rm ON  map.roleId = rm.id  where userName = ?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/login", "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/config/**", "/app/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/app/user/**")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password") 
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/user/dashboard")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();

        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired=true");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**Authorization part**
By pass authorization for resources like javascript and css which is stored in resources folder.

```
.antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/login", "/api/**").permitAll()
```

For Admin urls

```
.antMatchers("/config/**", "/app/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

For urls which can be accessed by multiple roles

```
.antMatchers("/app/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
```

And `.formLogin()` configuration:

```
.usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password") 
// Use above line of code if your login form param names are different 
// than defaults -> "username" "password"
.defaultSuccessUrl("/app/user/dashboard")
// If defaultSuccessUrl not configured then after login success redirects to "/"
```

**Exception Handling part**

```
.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
//If you want custom denied screen to be displayed.
```

Comment: If you want to know all defaults in spring security login authentication filter [refer my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764648/2825798) It also explains well about configuring userDetailsService for authentication.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I could not make it work. I replaced the argument query for `authoritiesByUsernameQuery()` method as you wrote and now it returns 2 columns `login` and `role` with entries `admin` and `ADMIN`, respectively. And I've added `.antMatchers("/mypage")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")`. And `usernameParameter("login"); passwordParameter("password");` But It still does not work.

Comment: Post another question explaining how you implemented. And current result with necessary details. So that I can see what you have done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256722/spring-security-gettiing-403-error-when-added-hasrole-method

Comment: I shown `ROLE_ADMIN` in screenshot i attached here. Might be you have not noticed here.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I did not know that it is important to add `ROLE_` prefix, sorry. I think I should read some documentation.